# Free a pointer to struct cause the program to get "stuck"

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

given the following C code:

```
struct list_element
{
    struct list_element * next;
};
typedef struct list_element list_element;

typedef struct
{
    list_element header;
    int value;

} *apple;

apple a = malloc(sizeof(apple));
a->value = 1;
free(a);
```

However, the program get "stuck" in the `free()` function (in release configuration, the program crash). I also tried `free(&a)` to free the dress that holds the pointer, but nothing seems to be works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I agree, it's a given API that I must use it. Yep, that's the code

Comment: Did you mean stuck instead of stack? I'm confused.

Comment: @tkausl yes, my bad

Comment: What's the err when the program crashes?

Comment: @KaiserKatze nothing meaningful, just "program.exe has triggered a breakpoint."

Comment: @NaveTseva Don't assume and thus neglect to tell.There's a vast difference between *stuck* and *triggered breakpoint*.

Comment: karma strike again don't hide pointer in typedef

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
apple a = malloc(sizeof(apple));
```

Will allocate memory with size of pointer not actual structure.

> Avoid typdefing structure to pointer;

```
typedef struct
{
    list_element header;
    int value;

} apple;
apple *a = malloc(sizeof(apple ));
```

or
Best approach would be referring  the `type` which `pointer` is holding like below.

```
typedef struct
{
    list_element header;
    int value;

} *apple;
apple a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
```

Comment: Thanks, but let's say I have to use typdefing structure to pointer, is there an elegant way to handle it?

Comment: @NaveTseva See the last line, where he keeps your typedef. Though you should know that `sizeof` is not a function, and those parentheses are thus superfluous when used with an expression (as it should nearly always be).

Comment: @NaveTseva you really should avoid hiding pointers behind typedefs. That's exactly why you've encountered the problem you were asking about. `apple a = malloc(sizeof(apple));` looks correct but it's wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Totally agreed, it's a struct of a given API, don't have control it's definitions or something, just need to use it

Comment: I always use two typedefs, eg. 'apple' for the struct and 'pApple' for the pointer to it.